# Who benefits of a tax reduction in subscription businesses? The company or the client?

Tags: european-union, tax-law, germany

1. Last year a client signed up for a yearly subscription of my product. He paid 14,99 € with 19 % taxes included.
2. This year the taxes are only 5 %.

How much does the client pay?

Why I asked: PayPal demands 14,99 € of my clients (I benefit of the tax reduction) and Stripe demands only 13,23 € (the client benefits of the tax reduction). EDIT: Both are gross prices with 5 % taxes included.

Comment: Well, what is written on the invoice? You cannot charge them 19% VAT but only pay 5% to the state, that would be fraud. But you can perhaps charge them 14,99€ incl 5% VAT, for example – but this would depend on how the contract is phrased (net or gross prices). Related question: if VAT had been raised to 25%, would you have eaten the cost or do you think you would have been allowed to raise the price? Most businesses *voluntarily* pass the reduced tax rate on to consumers, instead of increasing their net prices.

Comment: Both the 14,99 € and the 13,23 € are gross prices. So if I understand you right then you can choose wether to keep the gross price or to lower it in case of tax reduction.